Помогите понять как искать пользователей в базе данных, которые заходили сегодня и неделю назад библиотеки: aiogram, sqlalchemy, asyncpg, datetime
Помогите понять как искать пользователей в базе данных, которые заходили сегодня и неделю назад
библиотеки: aiogram, sqlalchemy, asyncpg, datetime
#requests
async def day(today):
    async with async_session() as session:
        users = await session.query(User).filter(User.date.days == today.days).all()
        users = users.count()
        return users

async def week(week):
    async with async_session() as session:
        users = await session.query(User).filter(abs(User.date.days - week.days) <= 7).all()
        return users

#admin_handlers
@admin.callback_query(F.data == 'day')
async def day(callback_query: CallbackQuery):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    a = day(today)
    await callback_query.message.answer(f'Количество пользователей: {a}')

@admin.callback_query(F.data == 'week')
async def week(callback_query: CallbackQuery):
    now_week = datetime.date.today()
    a = week(now_week)
    await callback_query.message.answer(f'Количество пользователей: {a}')

#models
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, String, BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, DeclarativeBase, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine

from config import DB_URL

engine = create_async_engine(url=DB_URL, echo=True, future=True)

async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine)


class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    tg_id = mapped_column(BigInteger)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    # age: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(none=True)
    # gender: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(none=True)
    date: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()


async def async_main():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)


Сначала их нужно туда записать, прежде чем искать
